# typeError: login is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

i don't know why this error is popping in my console and not my script is not working which I have include in it.
 it was working well before adding "form" tag. 
and the other error i am getting is

"A form was submitted in the windows-1252 encoding which cannot encode all Unicode characters, so user input may get corrupted. To avoid this problem, the page should be changed so that the form is submitted in the UTF-8 encoding either by changing the encoding of the page itself to UTF-8 or by specifying accept-charset=utf-8 on the form element."

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<title>
  LOG IN
</title>
<head>

</head>
<script >
 function login()
{
  var id,paswd,cpaswd;
  id=document.getElementById("name").value;
  paswd=document.getElementById("pass").value;
  cpaswd=document.getElementById("confirmation").value;

if(paswd!=cpaswd)
{ alert("password don't match");
  return false;
}


else
  { alert("successful")
return true;

  }

}

</script>
<body>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div align ="center" id="">
    <form method="post" onsubmit="return login()" action="/calculator.html"  >

      <h1>REGISTRATION </h1>

<input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" autocomplete="off" ><br><br>
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass" required><br><br>
<input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirmation" required><br><br><br><br>

<button id="login" onclick="login()" type="submit" >REGISTER</button>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script is neither in head section nor in body section. Perhaps that is why the browser cannot see the function.

Comment: I tried placing in head and body tag both but Still not working

Comment: Just use the standard `addEventListener` instead of obsolete inline event handlers and it’ll resolve a whole lot of issues. And next time try `console.log` to debug this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`login` is the `id` that you've given to your submit button and DOM elements exist in a Global scope, which overrides your function of the same name. Changing the function name and the call to it (or the button's `id`) solves the issue.

By the way, since you are using a `submit` button, you only need/want to call your function on the `submit` event of the form, not the `click` event of the button.

```js
function logins() {
  var id, paswd, cpaswd;
  id = document.getElementById("name").value;
  paswd = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  cpaswd = document.getElementById("confirmation").value;

  if(paswd!=cpaswd) { 
    alert("password don't match");
    return false;
  } else { 
    alert("successful")
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" onsubmit="return logins()" action="/calculator.html" onsubmit="return login()" >
  <h1>REGISTRATION </h1>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" autocomplete="off" ><br><br>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass" required><br><br>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirmation" required><br><br><br><br>

  <button id="login" type="submit" >REGISTER</button>
</form>
```

Comment: login is not a Javascript reserved word. http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Comment: @NawedKhan I didn't say it was a *JavaScript* reserved word. It is most likely bumping into a global property of `window`. Nonetheless, changing the function name to something else does solve the problem, so clearly the word `login` is being used for another purpose somewhere.

Comment: It’s because the button has the ID `login`. In non-strict mode this yields a global property.

Comment: @Xufox Ah! I didn't see that. I'll update.